# not getting pod gpu metrics from dcgm-exporter

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, prometheus

I have setup dcgm-exporter to collect metrics for GPU usage of pods but the pod field shows the name of dcgm-exporter and not the actual pod generating the workload.

> pod="dcgm-exporter-1634736248-7c6vs"

Is there a config to be made in order to get pod level GPU metrics?

Comment: From my understanding of the official NVIDIA documentation (https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/kubernetes/dcgme2e.html#setting-up-dcgm) it's necessary to have the dcgm-exporter pod in place but to get the final metrics you have to have everything else configured as well as per NVIDIA documentation here: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/kubernetes/dcgme2e.html#integrating-gpu-telemetry-into-kubernetes. Which documentation/tutorial have you followed?

Comment: have you deployed the NVIDIA plugin ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#deploying-nvidia-gpu-device-plugin Once installed kubernetes exposes nvidia.com/gpu as a schedulable resource

Answer (score -1):

Use the below ENV in the `dcgm-exported` daemonset/deployment manifest.

```yaml
- name: "DCGM_EXPORTER_KUBERNETES_GPU_ID_TYPE"
  value: "device-name"
```